# The app contains or inherits from non-public classes in payload/XXX.APP/XXX: UIKeyboard

Tags: ios, ios8, uikeyboard

I am getting this App Store error while submitting the app. I was able to submit the same app a month ago and i did not have this problem. last time i submitted, it gave me errors but it would still accept the binary atleast. Now it does not even accept the binary. I do use code as follows.

```
valueTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
```

I am not sure if any of my library is not meeting the expectation. Is there any other workaround for this?

If i have to send email to apple, should i also send the binary to them?
[image]

EDIT :  Brian, i have done both nm & strings on the .app file . Below is the result. Can you suggest what to do next?

[image]

Comment: Did you make changes to that class? I'm getting a similar error and starting to think it's a problem on Apple's end.

Comment: No I did not make any changes to the class. I am feeling that the apple validation process is broken.

Comment: Getting the same error, just tried submitting 10 min ago. Might be worth waiting a few hours and trying again. :/

Comment: It looks like they've also added a bunch of method names to the private list in the last few weeks. They've added "App" which was a class name I had for an NSManagedObject subclass. I added a prefix and it was accepted. I've also heard that we should be using 3 character prefixes to class names instead of the usual 2.

Comment: Yikes! If you're not referencing UIKeyboard directly in your code it may have come from a third party framework. You should `nm` any .a files you link against to hopefully narrow it down. Are you using any testing libraries?

Answer (score 3):

Your error is unrelated to that specific line of code.  When compiled that line reduces down to a call that is effectively:

```objc
objc_msgSend(valueTextField, SEL(setKeyboardType:), (NSInteger)2);
```

There would be no mention of UIKeyboard in your binary.

You can also verify that your code does not reference UIKeyboard by running `nm` and `strings` on your binary:

```bash
nm MyApp.app/MyApp | grep UIKeyboard
strings MyApp.app/MyApp | grep UIKeyboard
```

This will show you any string or symbol reference you might have to UIKeyboard.  If you don't have any, the commands should be empty otherwise nm would output something like:

```text
U _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIKeyboard
```

Based on the fact others have run into this, it seems like there's a problem with Apple's submission process right now.  If the problem does not go away on its own, you could try the three different submission channels:

- Upload via the [iTunes Connect Web UI](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/)
- Submitting your archive from within Xcode. Window -> Organizer -> Archives -> Submit...
- Submitting your app via Application Loader.

### Update

Looking at your edit, your app does in fact reference UIKeyboard.  Since it sounds like your code isn't using UIKeyboard a third-party library may be to blame.  You have a couple options:

#### Track down the commit where the change was introduced:

Since you have a previous release in the app store, you should be able to check out that version of the app from your SCM, build it, run `nm MyApp.app/MyApp | grep UIKeyboard` and verify you weren't referencing the class.  If this is not the case, things are going to be harder and you should skip to my next suggestion.

You can now track down the commit that introduced the dependency by bisecting your commits between the good and the bad.  If using git, [`git bisect`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) is your friend:

1. `git bisect master SHA_OR_TAG_OF_PREVIOUS_RELEASE`
2. Build app.
3. `nm MyApp.app/MyApp | grep UIKeyboard`
4. If good, `git bisect good`, otherwise `git bisect bad`.
5. Repeat steps 2 through 4 until you find the commit that introduced the problem.

Once you find the bad commit, it should be hopefully be clear what library you updated to introduce the problem.  You can check for new updates, revert it, or whatever is necessary to fix the problem.  If you can't figure out which one caused it immediately, you can perform the next step.

#### Run `nm` on frameworks and libraries used by your app:

Since you can't find a reference to `UIKeyboard` in your code, you're most likely linking to a library that references it.  You'll want to run `nm` on each of those libraries to track to the culprit.

You can find all the frameworks your app links to under "Build Phases" under the "Link Binary With Libraries" phase.  You can ignore system frameworks and libraries from other projects in the workspace and just focus on any third-party `.a` files or frameworks.

If you're using Cocoapods for everything you can go ahead and check `libPods-*.a` to quickly see if any pods reference the code.  If you hit a match, rerun `nm` piping into `less` and keep pressing up until you see a pathname and object file name that will point you to the responsible library.

Otherwise, run `nm` on each .a file and the binary file in each .framework directory.

```
nm myLibrary.a | grep UIKeyboard
nm SomeComponent.framework/SomeComponent | grep UIKeyboard
```

Once you get a match you can check to see if there's a new version of the framework or report the issue.  If you find it in a library that you shouldn't have been linking to in production, find a way to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was inside the "LOOKBACK" framework that i recently added. This is .framework file and i was not sure how to do a nm on a .framework file. I tried the below. Both gave me error "can't map file"

nm Lookback.framework | grep UIKeyboard

strings Lookback.framework | grep UIKeyboard

As Brian mentioned i have done nm,strings on all other static  library (.a files) i was using, which did not reveal anything concrete.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear.  You can run `nm Lookback.framework/Lookback`.  Looking at their documentation, there are two versions of the framework, the standard one and "LookbackSafe" which can be used in the app store.

Comment: I used the LookbackSafe only. I guess this does not work. I have never used LookbackHD.

Comment: Maybe they had a bug. I downloaded the latest version and HD references UIKeyboard and Safe doesn't.